# Representing product specifications

Tags: c#, .net, ooad

I need to extend my domain model: products may have different specifications. E.g. motherboard specs are different from monitor specs.

there are two entities:

```
public class Product {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    // ..Price, Title, Manufacturer properties
}
```

where `Category` is

```
public class Category {
    // ..ctor to initialize this.Specs as List or as Dictionary

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<String> Specs { get; set; }
}
```

Is that a normal way to solve this I mean putting `ICollection<String> Specs` inside `Category` entity?

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC` & `Raven DB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a set of specifications is part of a category of products then this is probably a good way to model it.

Though, a specification should probably be its own concept rather than a simple string (I say that without any knowledge of your specific requirements).

So, instead of an `ICollection<string>` have an `ICollection<Specification>`.